# get file type after downloading from IPFS

Tags: filenames, fs, file-extension, ipfs

I'm using ipfs to download files... but ipfs does not have filenames or extensions.

How can I properly set the extension for the saved file, based on the downloaded data?

Answer (score 2):

You can add files with `ipfs add -w` to "wrap" them in a directory. This will preserve the filename.

There are also plans to record metadata like mime types along with files but, unfortunately, progress has gotten a bit stuck on this front.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to conclusively get the file extension in IPFS, so instead, you can look at the contents of the file to infer its file type (using [`file-type`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type), for example)

When you have the full contents of the file in a buffer, you can do:

```js
import {fileTypeFromBuffer} from 'file-type';

let buffer = /* buffer of file from IPFS */;

// undefined or string of file extension
let ext = (await fileTypeFromBuffer(buffer))?.ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to do this in a `React` app on the frontend this works :

```js
let contentType = await fetch(imageUrl)
  .then(response => {
    return response.blob().then(blob => {
      return {
        contentType: response.headers.get("Content-Type"),
        raw: blob
      }
    })
  })
  .then(data => {
    return data.contentType
  })
```

`file-type` is intended for use in `Node` apps, not on the client side.

If you try to use a library intended for `Node` then you will get errors that relate to the library's internal dependencies on built-in `Node` modules which are not available in the browser. You should use a different library for making HTTP requests from the browser; I'd suggest using the browser's built-in `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

you must get the program file type, then import the extension name on the program name you downloaded from the buffer

i hope you understand this